# Why has Minecraft generated this 1-chunk wide strip of world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I recently installed Dynmap, and viewing the map I noticed this 1-chunk wide strip extending directly south from spawn for about 16000 blocks. It can't have been generated by a player, otherwise it would be much wider than one chunk.

I don't have any plugins installed that would have generated this (I don't think?); I have done some manual world editing to merge two worlds together (using a [custom, Prismarine-based tool](https://github.com/apaleslimghost/minecraft-world-splicer/)), but that can't have generated anything.

Why would this have generated?

Plugin list:

- Dynmap
- DiscordSRV
- EmojiChat
- bPermissions

[image: screenshot of minecraft Dynmap map]

Comment: Someone flying really fast with an Elytra, perhaps?

Comment: i'm reasonably sure that would still generate out to the render distance though?

Comment: @KaraBrightwell No, if they move sufficiently fast. Chunks right under the player generate at high priority, but the rest is pretty slow, and if the player moves away fast enough, they won't be generated. But the trail of a fast flyer wouldn't be nearly this regular - splotches where more chunks generated, breaks where nothing generated. A flying machine could leave a trail like that but it's unlikely it would do it on vanilla server; and would require some tricky conditions. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVa3Qh5pUCo) for a similar case.

Comment: Couldn't someone just set their render distance to one chunk?

Comment: @Corsaka Even if you could at least 25 chunks will be generated (at least in 1.15+). Every 'isle' of entity-processing chunks gets a ring of lazy chunks and a ring of non-ticking chunks generated around it.

Comment: @KaraBrightwell I'd suggest to go to the end of the strip and check if you find a flying machine there.

Comment: there's no flying machine.

Comment: something interesting: there's a straight line of generated chunks in the corresponding place in the Nether (to about Z=2600, which corresponds with the end of the overworld strip). this is generated to normal render distance. does generating the Nether generate overworld chunks?

Comment: @KaraBrightwell Normally it doesn't, definitely not vanilla. Sure there are *ways* but they wouldn't generate a 1-wide strip (would be at least 7-wide), and they are way too tedious to be practical on this scale. I suppose either your server or one of the plugins misbehaving.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99% sure that your splicer is extremely old. Additionally, you should take a look at this.

According to [splicer page,](https://github.com/apaleslimghost/minecraft-world-splicer)

> This tool has been tested somewhat but it will overwrite chunks in the target world without prompting and ***it might corrupt your world.***
>
> unmaintained, does not work in minecraft 1.17 onwards

This is a red flag. It's probably the splicer being annoying.

But then I saw this[(Dynmap page),](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/dynmap%C2%AE.274/):

> The following mods are known to support dynmap integration without needing an add-on:
>
> - DeathTPPlus
> - xWarp
> - Vanish No Packet

With a plugin that hasn't been tested much and one that's not extremely compatible, no wonder your world is glitched.

Answer (score -2):

try to see if someone was flying fast toward it. or check your seed. if it is the 32 bit integer limit, try generating a world by random seed. otherwise, the many plugins have made the world generating hard for the Minecraft server/world. also check the f3 screen and go to chunk cache and if the 1 chunk area is centered in 0,0 then it might be the worlds priority to generate a `X` and `Y` 1 chunk area, in case you are flying long distances via elytra to save lag and crashing of the application.